# Authentication using username or email

Tags: feathersjs

Using feathers-authentication it is possible to authenticate a user using a configurable username field. At the moment, I can configure authentication to use either the `username` OR `email` fields of my user model, but I would like to offer both options `username` AND `email` to our users.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, it is possible to concatenate authentication methods so the solution should be something like:

```
app.configure(auth({ secret: 'super secret' }))
  .configure(local()) // defaults usernameField to 'email'
  .configure(local({ // support username
    name: 'local-username',
    usernameField: 'username'
}));
```

A more complete example can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/pull/148#issuecomment-261506180